# How correct use terelik getGridMasterTableView().filter() methot on javascript on client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I use telerik radGriD funcrion on javascript client-side:

```
    getGridMasterTableView().get_filterExpressions().clear(); - clear array of filter expression. 

    getGridMasterTableView().filter(fieldName, strData, GetExpressionValue(fieldExpression)); - add elenent in array filter expression.
```

when I call this getGridMasterTableView().filter(fieldName, strData, GetExpressionValue(fieldExpression)) method two times, when fieldName allways the same, the method getGridMasterTableView().get_filterExpressions() in watch shows that it simply rewrites element but I need that it add new element. How resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to apply two filters on the same column? From the sound of things you are filtering once, and then trying to filter that same result once more. You can only have one filter on a column at a time, so when you call the filter() method the second time it just removes the old filter and filters according to the last filter() call.

For more information regarding client-side filtering I recommend looking over [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-gridtableview-filter.html).